# Store sf::Texture in a static variable in a dll

Tags: c++, sfml

Actually i use a dll to export some methods to a unmanaged application.

I need to create a static var for the sf::Texture, but when i try, the dll is not correctly initialized.

I just add this line:

```
static Texture test3;
```

And the dll stop.

Comment: It is not clear what means that DLL stop. Do you get misterious crash? Do you fail linking? Do the compiler complain about annything? Do your application crash at a very precise point? (I think it crash when using the texture anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the effects of "static" as qualifier, those are covered in other answers. If you want to use "static" then you should know what "static" is doing.

[In a C++ namespace does the `static` qualifier have any effect when prefixing non-member subroutines declared in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007879/in-a-c-namespace-does-the-static-qualifier-have-any-effect-when-prefixing-no)

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but I think you may want to access that value through functions defined in your DLL.

In example

source.cpp

```
static Texture *myInternalTexture;

void InitInternalTexture(){
    myInternalTexture = new Texture( blah);
}

Texture *GetInternalTexture(){
    return myInternalTexture;
}

void ReleaseInternalTexture(){
    delete myInternalTexture;
}
```

Depending on your use you may prefer to access a reference of your texture or do a copy, I don't know what you need to do. In case you can easily adapt the code above to work with your Texture type.